What is the equivalent of doing `git reset <file>` / `git reset` with the shipped vc?
I sometimes want to unstage changes. From the console I can use git reset or git reset <file>.
I couldn't find anything related in the docs or via C-x v C-h for vc, but it seems that this should be possible.
How would I do this with vc?

If you want to just undo the changes, go with C-x v u. This is all you need for all practical purposes.  For sophisticated things, there is always magit.

vc-revert is an autoloaded interactive compiled-function in `vc.el'.
It is bound to C-x v u.  It can also be invoked from the menu: Tools → Version Control → Revert to Base Version

(vc-revert)

Revert working copies of the selected fileset to their repository contents.
This asks for confirmation if the buffer contents are not identical
to the working revision (except for keyword expansion).
Probably introduced at or before Emacs version 24.1.
[back]


Thanks, that's it. Somehow I got the impression that this is only for registerd files, but you're right!
